# Session is not staying active PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

This is just a test run for a website that I am developing. I'm testing to find the best, most efficient way to submit orders to a database from multiple forms in html which is fine. The problem is the PHP sessions. You'll see in the code that on line 2 and line 7, I'm printing out the session_status function that returns either 0, 1 or 2. 2 being active, 1 being none active and 0 being disabled.

The first session_status echo statement prints 1, therefore the if statement runs, thus starting the session and needed session variables, but the session variables (those two arrays) are being reset every time the script runs... The session doesn't stay active, so that if statement block runs every time. Not sure why.

I've tried to solve it by not having an if statement at the beginning of the script, but just by having session_start(); but I still need an if statement like the one I have now to be able to declare session variables (the 2 arrays that I push to)

```
<?php 
echo session_status();
if(!(session_status() == 2)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["items"] = array();
    $_SESSION["prices"] = array();
    echo session_status();
}



if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    foreach($_POST as $item) {
        foreach($item as $key => $value) {
            array_push($_SESSION["items"], $key);
            array_push($_SESSION["prices"], $value);
        }
    }

    foreach($_SESSION["items"] as $element) {
        echo "<li>Item: $element</li>";
    }
}

echo print_r($_SESSION["items"]);
echo "\n";
echo print_r($_SESSION["prices"]);


/* Firearm class */
    class Firearm {
        function __construct($component, $component_price) {
            $this->component = $component;
            $this->component_price = $component_price;
        }
    }

    class Ar extends Firearm {

    }

    /* Pattern class */
    class Pattern {
        function __construct($pattern, $pattern_price) {
            $this->pattern = $pattern;
            $this->pattern_price = $pattern_price;
        }
    }

    /* Color class */
    class Color {
        function __construct($color, $color_price) {
            $this->color = $color;
            $this->color_price = $color_price;
        }
    }

    /* Ar objects */
    $upper = new Ar("upper", 67);

    /* Pattern objects */
    $digital = new Pattern("digital", 25);

    /* color objects */
    $gray = new Color("gray", 25);
    $blue = new Color("blue", 25);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your build, your way</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" id="ar_form">
        <label for="upper">Upper-></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="component[upper]" value="<?= $upper->component_price; ?>">

        <hr>

        <label for="digital">Digital</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pattern[digital]" value="<?= $digital->pattern_price; ?>">

        <hr>

        <label for="gray">Gray</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="color[gray]" value="<?= $gray->color_price; ?>">
        <label for="blue">Blue</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="color[blue]" value="<?= $blue->color_price; ?>">
        
        <button type="submit">Create part</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, please do not put multiple classes in a single PHP file. Use seperate files and a proper autoloader for this to keep each file maintainable

Comment: @NicoHaase it helps, but still doesn't explain why my session is being killed every run, there's just one file and the session is being started... Every time it runs, it prints 12 (1 for the first echo session_status) and (2 for the other in the if block)

Comment: I think if it works, it should print 22

Comment: Actually just 2 because the second wouldn't run

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The arrays that hold session data are being overwritten by the same variables being declared because the session doesn't stay active. Therefore the arrays that should hold data from multiple form submits are being overwritten every time the form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

`session_status()` returns 1 before calling `session_start()`, which is required at *some* point to use the `$_SESSION`. You should check the session values instead of checking `!(session_status() == 2)`, and call `start_session()` anyway.

```php
<php
echo session_status();
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["items"])) $_SESSION["items"] = array();
if(!isset($_SESSION["prices"])) $_SESSION["prices"] = array();
```